# The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared

Tags: php, html

When I click on my form's submit button the following error message appears:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

insert.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>insert page</title></head>
    <body>
    <h1> Insert Page </h1>
        <form action="insert.php" method="post"  enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" >
         <p>Title:<input type="text" name="title" size="40" /></p>
         <p>Price:<input type= "text" name="price" size="40" /></p>
         <p><input type="submit" value="Insert" />
         <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
        </form>    
    </body>
</html>
```

insert.php:

```
<?php
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];

    echo $title;
?>
```

I don't know where is the problem in my code. Please help me.

Comment: Some good reading: [Declaring character encodings in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations)

Comment: Try naming you .html page to .php: `insert.html` -> `insert.php`. And name your form handling file (`insert.php`) to `insert_action.php` or something. (Not sure if it helps but I wouldn't mix `html` and `php` pages when using PHP.)

Comment: Oh dear, this was an old question. Didn't notice the dates because of the new answer...

Comment: @xing, Which browser are you using?

Comment: This also works with bare HTML

Comment: You have a typo in your code.
`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
Should be
**`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />`**
Also
`<meta charset="utf-8">`
as mention down there should work for ya, as It was for me, when I had this kind of error.

Answer (score 352):

Add this as a first line in the HEAD section of your HTML template

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

> Note: if any line between `<head>` and these meta line (Even if it's a
> commented note) problem will remain, so make sure you added meta line
> after `<head>` directly

Comment: second line produces this error in W3 validator for docytype html:
`Bad value encoding for attribute http-equiv on element meta.`

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

Comment: @yitwail I just excluded the second line, and it worked.

Comment: I'm using firefox. I typed both of them and now it show me nothing on page. What should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: Very few of us type text files in UTF-8.  Most text files are in ISO-8859-1 format.  Look and see what your text editor is producing, and if it is ISO-8859-1 then use <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

Comment: First meta link works beautifully: `<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">`.

Comment: `encoding` is not among the documented values of [`http-equiv`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#pragma-directives).

Answer (score 75):

I had the same problem with the most basic situation and my problem was solved by inserting this tag into the head of the document:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The character encoding (which is actually UTF-8) of the html document was not declared.

More on it [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#charset), and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#examples).

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem when I ran my form application in Firefox. Adding `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` in the html code solved my issue in Firefox.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Voice clip upload</title>
  <script src="voiceclip.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Upload Voice Clip</h2>
  <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>
    <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 21):

Well when you post, the browser only outputs `$title` - all your HTML tags and doctype go away. You need to include those in your `insert.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>insert page</title></head>
<body>
<?php 

   $title = $_POST["title"];
   $price = $_POST["price"];

  echo $title;


 ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having a similar problem, and your answer helped fixed it (I was missing the meta http-equiv... line).

Answer (score 4):

You have to change the file from .html to .php.

and add this following line

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: This is a better/more direct/efficient to way to set the charset, if you can use this method.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial page is a complete HTML page containing a form, the contents of which are posted to insert.php when the submit button is clicked, but insert.php needs to process the form's contents and do something with them, like add them to a database, or output them to a new page. Your current insert.php just outputs the contents of the title field, so your browser tries to interpret that as an HTML page, and fails, obviously, because it isn't valid HTML (i.e. it isn't contained in an 'HTML' tag, etc.).

Your insert.php needs to output the necessary HTML, and insert the form data in there somewhere.

For example:

```
<?php 

   $title = $_POST["title"];
   $price = $_POST["price"];

  echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
  echo '<head>';
  echo '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
  echo '<title>';
  echo $title;
  echo '</title>';
  echo '</head>';
  echo '<body>';
  echo 'Hello, world.';
  echo '</body>';

 ?>
```

Comment: That's odd. Can you post your code as an addition to the original question?