# jquery ajax post , trying to post a json , doesnt work

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, http-post

I have a small php server that i developed. The server waits to serve json files that will be sent to him.

I created an html page and i am using jquery to try send a json file to my server.

I have a button and when i press it :

```
$("button").click(function(){

                     var data = '{"deviceUUID":"25f998", "os":"bb", "pushToken":"l1355436gdfsfaddsl"}';
                     alert("User: " + userId + "\n" + "Data: " + data);

                     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "http://192.148.2.123/Server_CityInfo/register.php",
                         data: data,
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         dataType: "json"
                         });


                 });
```

However the json file that arrives in the server is empty.. I know the server works , cause i have done post requests to it through java , obj-c , c# ...

What could be the problem here?  The data variable on alert prints : `{"deviceUUID":"25f998", "os":"bb", "pushToken":"l1355436gdfsfaddsl"}` which is in the right json format , that my server accepts.

**THIS IS MY SEVER SIDE , PHP**

```
// We use php://input to get the raw $_POST results.
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_post = json_decode($json, true);

//creating variables from received json
$deviceUDID = $json_post['deviceUUID'];
$os = $json_post['os'];
$pushToken = $json_post['pushToken'];
```

So when i try to print the `deviceUUID` , or `os` or `pushToken` they are empty. In my database , that they are automatically inserted they appear as `NULL` . That means that the post request arrives , but empty... or in wrong format..

Comment: Any error on console ?

Comment: what console , i just run it on my browser? How can i debug this thing? The request is made to my server. But the server says that the deviceUUID , the os and the pushToken it received were all NULL. So i guess i dont send the json file as i think , or is in wrong format

Comment: Yes browser console : `ctrl + shift + J `

Comment: add a `success` parameter to the ajax request, something simple like an `alert`, so you know if it returns or not. You might also want to add `dataType:"json"` as a parameter as well.

Comment: the browser console doesnt show errors , i have the dataType:"json" cant you see it? And i didnt understand the success part.

Comment: did you try to post your data as js object, instead of a string :
 var data = {"deviceUUID":"25f998", "os":"bb", "pushToken":"l1355436gdfsfaddsl"}; ?

Its the way I use $.post

Comment: if i do that , data prints me : [object Object] but sadly is empty again on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display the console depend on your browser.
Chrome/ff : Ctrl + shift + i
IE : f12 then click refresh

for the success part, he means use a callback once ajax call is finished. You can use either `done` or `fail` or `allways` :

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://192.148.2.123/Server_CityInfo/register.php",
     data: data,
     contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json"
}).allways(function(response, status, xhr){
     console.log(response);
     console.log(status);
     console.log(xhr);
});
```

You will se the result of your call in the console.

Comment: Timestamp: 5/17/2013 5:59:49 PM
Error: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.  

Timestamp: 5/17/2013 6:01:29 PM
Error: TypeError: $.ajax(...).allways is not a function

Comment: WUT ? Ok, let me edit my answer, but I have never seen it before.

Comment: I fixed the error from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996257/the-character-encoding-of-the-html-document-was-not-declared i just added the 2 meta lines. Now i dont get any error and still the server receives empty json :p

Comment: if you delete the `dataType : 'json'` and put quotes arround your data variable. You agree you are sending a simple String to your server ?! Does it read this string or it is null too ?

Answer (score 0):

On the following line, you are setting data to a string value:

```
var data = '{"deviceUUID":"25f998", "os":"bb", "pushToken":"l1355436gdfsfaddsl"}';
```

If you want this to be a Javascript Object (JSON), you need to remove the single quotes:

```
var data = {"deviceUUID":"25f998", "os":"bb", "pushToken":"l1355436gdfsfaddsl"};
```

Check out http://www.json.org/ for more infomation.  This website has lots of information and tools on the JSON format.

Comment: I did it. See my comments after my question , when someone already mentioned that and i answered the new problem