# how to fix The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared

Tags: php, html, mysql

My website runs in `localhost` without any errors; but when I added my site to `CPpanel` and run `members.php` page disapeared (it shows white background).
 Inspecting  the page in console displays this error message :

```
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
```

Inspecting the element shows only these lines:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>


    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could it already be answered here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996257/the-character-encoding-of-the-html-document-was-not-declared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error you get, please add this to your `<head> ... </head>`:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-5">
```

If the charset above did not work, please try this instead:

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

And I hope you defined the before BODY part of your pages as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<HEAD>

    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

<title> Your Title</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
....
```

**EDIT 2:**
Before including other any other PHP files in your `members.php`, type this line first:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: @Tje Please, try the second option (I edited my answer)

Comment: same white page.not changed anything.

Comment: @Tje is `members.php` the only page that has this problem ? All other pages are ok ?

Comment: Yes other pages are ok.only that happen in members.php.thanks

Comment: @Tje Ok. Do you have other file included in `members.php` page ?

Comment: @Bengueradj Yes dbconfig.php is included and there also some links to some pages.

Comment: @Tje Please, try the solution in EDIT 2 of my answer, and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you something like this in header? You put instead of utf-8 encoding of your file.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```