# Why isn't this function loading on page load? Happens only in Firefox. Works in Chrome and Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Here's the code:

When I try to load the function myList() on page load Console shows "mylist entered" in Chrome, Opera but doesn't seem to work in Firefox.

However the function myList() works(even in Firefox) from inside the keyup function which I have commented in the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>List</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log('ready');
    $(function () {
        // body...
        $('#omnibox').focus();
        if (window.localStorage) {
            //Enter key binding
            var todo = document.querySelector('#omnibox');
            //debugger;
            $('#omnibox').keyup(function(e){
                if(e.keyCode == 13)
                {
                    console.log("Enter pressed!");
                    var todoVal = document.querySelector('#omnibox').value;
                    //myList(); 

                }
            });
            myList();
            function myList()
                {
                    console.log("mylist entered");
                }
        }

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>List</h2>
    <input type="text" id="omnibox">
    <div id='searchWrapper'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't put the function definition inside the `if`. That seems to be deferring the function definition until it gets to that code, which is after you try to call it.

Comment: excellent answer by barmar also try putting some meta tags for errors removal see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996257/the-character-encoding-of-the-html-document-was-not-declared

Comment: Add this as a first line in the HEAD section of your HTML template

<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help :)