# MongoDB installed but new MongoClient() doesn't work

Tags: php, mongodb

I just installed MongoDB on my Linux (12.04) with its extension for PHP, and both seems to be well installed (phpinfo() shows infos about MongoDB, enabled etc.).

But when i want to load a page containing the following code, nothing is displayed:

```
<?php

    $m = new MongoClient();

    echo "Connection to database sucessfull";

    $db=$m->mydb;

    echo "Database mydb selected";

?>
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: What does the error log says?

Comment: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996257/the-character-encoding-of-the-html-document-was-not-declared)

Comment: @MartinHenriksen i already tried this solution, it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I think the problem doesn't come from character encoding because when i echo something before new mongoClient() it works...

Comment: do u have driver for mongodb to php connectivity installed their. I faced the same problem on my linux remote server where i managed to find the solution by installing the driver by command pecl install mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual Syntactic code is this:

```
    $m = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost', [
    'username' => 'abc',
    'password' => 'abc@123',
    'db'       => 'abc'
    ]);
```

May be you try once. 
Use get_last_error() and dump it on screen and send.