# HTML-Form to Database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, web

I've been trying to connect this HTML-Form with my MySql-Database so I can get messages sent to me from my website. But I keep Getting this message:

***"The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. "***

I've tried many different things from other people who had the same problem but it didn't seem to work for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ABeeZee'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/navshrink.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contact.css">
    </head>



 <div class="contactCon">
       <form class="contactForm" action="contactForm.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
          <ul class="flex-container">
             <li class="flex-item">
                <ul class="flex-container2">
                    <li class="flex-item2">enter code here
                        <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your First Name..">
                    </li>
                    <li class="flex-item2">
                        <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your Last Name..">
                    </li>
                    <li class="flex-item2">
                        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-mail..">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="flex-item">
                    <label id="subject-label" for="subject">Subject:</label>
                    <textarea type="text" id="subject" name="message" placeholder="Write Me Something.."></textarea>
                    <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </li>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </form>
    </div>
```

And here is my PHP-code for the form:

```
<?php
  // Create Variables for Database Information
  $host = 'xxxxxx';
  $userName = 'xxxxxxx';
  $dbPassword = 'xxxxxx';
  $dbName = 'xxxxxxxx';

  // Create Connection to the Database
  $con = mysqli_connect($host,$userName,$dbPassword,$dbName);

  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    // Create Variables for every Input
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['message']);



    // Insert Input into the Database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contactMe(firstname, lastname, email, message)
      VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$message')";

    // Check for Errors
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    // Close Connection
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996257/the-character-encoding-of-the-html-document-was-not-declared

Comment: I have seen that post and that didn't solve my problem, so I guess I have a right to post my own code here.

Comment: Certainly you have the 'right' - I only showed there is at least one question like yours (new people often 'post before search' and as you didn't have any answers, maybe that post could help you - if not an answer, perhaps at least help reform your question. For instance, the other post looks like a Firefox only issue - have you tried other browsers, etc. as they talk about?  Tell what is truly different about your issue (because, to me, it looks the same, so tell what you have tried, etc. that makes this really unique) - people will help.